# How does Debezium set the Kafka message timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I did not find any documentation about how the Kafka message timestamp is set by Debezium - and if it is set at all.

From comparing the values the Kafka message timestamp is always behind the timestamp of the change to the database table (source.ts_ms), and also behind the time the change got processed by Debezium (ts_ms). This suggests that the Kafka message timestamp is just the one that is set to ingestion time by the Kafka broker.

Does anybody knows some details about if and how Debezium sets the Kafka message timestamp in the sink topic it populates?

I am using the Debezium connector for SQL server for the case that this makes a difference.

Comment: No, not yet - I hoped that others already did :-)

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking the [source.timestamp.mode](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-source-timestamp-mode) parameter. As per documentation (liked before), its default value `commit` should set the `ts_ms` to the time when the record was committed to the database.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is an important configuration value that should not be set wrong in my connector configuration. But it does not tell which of the timestamps is used as the Kafka message timestamp (or if the Kafka brokers just use the ingestion time here).

Answer (score 0):

Debezium does not set neither Kafka Connect timestamp nor Kafka message timestamp. The former is left empty, the latter is managed by Kafka Connect.